# Encoded password does not look like BCrypt (Spring Security)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

Написал маленькое приложение с использованием Spring Security, авторизация через БД, пароли в базе хранятся в кодировке BCrypt. Сначала все работало хорошо без ошибок, получалось залогиниться, а потом вдруг перестало работать (в коде (вроде бы) ничего не трогал, хотя как тогда такое может быть).

При вводе логина и пароля в форму и нажатия кнопки "submit" в консоли Идеи выводится сообщение "**Encoded password does not look like BCrypt**". Пошелестел Гугл, покрутил разные фрагменты кода, пока ничего не помогло (пробовал использовать другой password encoder, добавлять префикс {bcrypt} перед паролем в БД у убирал явное указания encoder'a в конфигурации).

*SecurityConfig.class*

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
public SecurityConfig(@Qualifier("userDetailsServiceImplementation") UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
    this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
}

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/auth/login").permitAll()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/auth/success")
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/auth/logout", "POST"))
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .clearAuthentication(true)
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/auth/login");

}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
}

protected PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
}

@Bean
protected DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    return daoAuthenticationProvider;
}
```

}

*Таблица БД:*
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Консоль:*
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если нужна еще какая-то информация, допишу.

Заранее, всем спасибо за советы:)

Answer (score 1):

Решение оказалось очень простым, а причина достаточно смешной, но не очевидной. При копировании хэша с bcrypt генератора в конце строки оказывался пробел, из-за этого вводимый в форму пароль не соответствовал хэшу:)